# getting blob data from form data request in expressJs

Tags: node.js, ajax, rest, express

Right now I'm sending a file to my expressjs server using as formdata using ajax.

```
    const fileChooser = document.getElementById('config-file-upload');
    const file = fileChooser.files[0];
    
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "upload-doc",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
    });
```

This sends the data to my server just fine but when I go to get the file in the server, it always comes back undefined.

```
    app.post('/upload-doc', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

I've tried using libraries like multer but i still get undefined when i try to access the files

```
   const upload = multer({dest: 'tmp/uploads'});

   app.post('upload-doc', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.files);
   });
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Keep `multer ` way and use `const file = $("config-file-upload")[0].files[0];` instead of `const file = fileChooser.files[0];`

Comment: @hoangdv After I did that, I ran into an error saying boundary not found. From what I saw on other stackoverflow posts, removing the content type header should fix it but after doing that, I'm still getting undefined. I've also tried setting the content type header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' without any luck either. Could it be related to the charset in the headers or maybe some sort of other character encoding issue?